# Las imágenes no se muestran usando {{asset('ruta/'.$nombre->archivo)}}, Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, imagen

```
<img  src="class='group list-group-image' '{{URL::asset('storage/'.$foto->foto)}}'" width="300" ><br>
{{ucwords($foto->descripcion)}}
```

imprimo la ruta `{{asset('storage/'.$foto->foto)}}` y la copio en elnavegador y me muestra la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Diria que tienes fatal el código HTML. Prueba con `<img  src="{{URL::asset('storage/'.$foto->foto)}}" class="group list-group-image" width="300" ><br>
{{ucwords($foto->descripcion)}} ` a ver que tal

Comment: Es que le he dado vueltas para ver como funciona y nada, hice lo que señalas ahí y tampoco, use esta forma y si las muestra, solo que no se si es la mejor practica:  src="../public/storage/{{$foto->foto}}"

Comment: en otro lado usé el asset de esta forma y funciona <img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$cliente->logoCliente}}" width="40" height="30">. No se cual será el problema del otro caso, hice lo mismo y tampoco funciona, solo funciona colocando la ruta

Comment: No uso laravel, pero si esto último que has comentado te funciona entonces quizás el otro deberias ponerlo así también:  `<img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$foto->foto}}" class="group list-group-image" width="300" ><br> {{ucwords($foto->descripcion)}}`

Comment: ya lo hice y tampoco funciona, realmente no le veo la lógica, las dos imágenes están en la carpeta storage y dentro de esta, están en carpetas distintas, y la opción de colocar la ruta completa src="../public/storage/{{$foto->foto}}", podría hacerlo así? es la única forma que me muestra las imágenes

Comment: si, claro, puedes ponerlo como quieras, mientras funcione :-)  Pero yo de ti miraria mediante el inspector de tu navegador (pulsa F12)  el código fuente para ver el resultado en HTML de `<img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$foto->foto}}"` y ver como lo ha resuelto, y de ahi sacar más conclusiones para solucionar el error.

Comment: Gracias Master, voy a revisar el inspector, porque use la misma sintaxis en otra vista  y funciona, solo en el reporte es que no funciona.